# How can I use azure ad access token which is got from SPA to protect backend api?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-active-directory

I want to use azure AD as authentication.
If user who is in certain organization logged in from SPA, and give access token to backend, then I want to permit access from SPA.
So, I want to check if token passed from SPA is valid or not. 
How can I do this?, Or Can I do this?

I want to build backend server with node.js app, and deploy backend app to app service or Azure Container Registry.

---

I think bearerStrategy would work.

Ref https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad

> BearerStrategy uses Bearer Token protocol to protect web resource/api.
>   It works in the following manner: User sends a request to the
>   protected web api which contains an access_token in either the
>   authorization header or body. Passport extracts and validates the
>   access_token, and propagates the claims in access_token to the verify
>   callback and let the framework finish the remaining authentication
>   procedure. On successful authentication, passport adds the user
>   information to req.user and passes it to the next middleware, which is
>   usually the business logic of the web resource/api. In case of error,
>   passport sends back an unauthorized response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past, there was an ADAL version for node apps. I don't know if it's still valid or not, but here are useful links:

https://medium.com/@liangjunjiang/verify-and-decode-azure-activity-directory-token-bc72cf7010bc

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/authentication-flows-app-scenarios

Comment: Do you know what Is "Web api"  in document ? Does "web api" includes backend which I created by node.js? "Web api" and "Web app" differs??

Comment: web api is just rest endpoints, while web apps can also serve html pages